# Android. Keyboard never shows up

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to show the keyboard in emulator for my EditText but whatever i try it doesn't appear.

This is how i declare it in XML file:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.05"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:ems="10"
     >

</EditText>
```

This is how i work with it in java file:

```
private void createTextEdit()
{
    EditText searchTextField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);
    searchTextField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
           System.out.println("AFTER TEXT CHANGED");                                                             
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
        int start, int count, int after)
        {
             System.out.println("BEFORE TEXT CHANGED " + s);
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,
                int start, int before, int count)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    });

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(searchTextField, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

And also i declared the following in the Manifest file:

```
<activity 
        android:name = "com.blabla.blablabla.MyActivity" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible">
    </activity>
```

And the keyboard is never shown. What am i missing?

Comment: try to delete `  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(searchTextField, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);`

Comment: @pietmau it doesn't help

Comment: youre using the Emulator, correct?

Comment: @pietmau yes, emulator

Comment: you are sure that your emulator does not have "hardware keyboard present"?

Comment: @pietmau i'm not sure. i have no idea what's that

Comment: @pietmau i looked in AVD manager and, yes hardware keyboard present is checked

Comment: @pietmau i unchecked it and it helped. if you wanna gain reputation answer me and i'll accept your answer

Comment: Answer posted. Thanks for the reputation. Good luck for your work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that your Emulator has not "Hardware keyboard present".

Answer (score 1):

Code work perfectly fine on device. According to me the emulator is having the hard keypad open so it will not show soft keypad. try to run this code on device.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
<EditText
....
<requestFocus /> 
</EditText>
```

Comment: you can add this line to manifest.xml android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"

Comment: are you testing in emulator or device?

Comment: i'm doing that in emulator

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25520/discussion-between-kirit-and-andrey-chernukha)

Answer (score 0):

Try out to force the softkeyboard to open as below:

> ```
>   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
>   imm.showSoftInput(searchTextField, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED); <-- change here.
> ```